# Getting an authed Facebook user's age without further permissions prompts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

With the Facebook Graph API, is it possible to get a user's age (or age range) without first prompting for the `user_birthday` or `friends_birthday` permission?

Comment: The user's birthday. Requires `user_birthday` or `friends_birthday` permission [User](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't (-_-;)

Age requires `user_birthday` or `friends_birthday` permission.

Example http://graph.facebook.com/68310606562?fields=id,name,birthday

If not simply you can get the founder age.

Comment: What do you mean by `the founder age`?

Comment: @dorkitude the example link is belong to Facebook founder :p

Comment: The link you mentioned in the answer has been updated with the new code and does not work, returns false for now.

Answer (score 3):

This depends; if you are building a canvas app you can parse the *signed_request* parameter, which will have an age range (max/min), which should give you something to go off of.

Comment: You will also receive the same signed request and by association the same age range attribute in tab applications.

Comment: Well, not exactly true, I tried the signed_request parameter but does not have the age range tried this code,$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

$locale = $signed_request['user']['locale'];
$country = $signed_request['user']['country'];

// get age range of current user
$age_min = isset($signed_request['user']['age']) && isset($signed_request['user']['age']['min']) ? $signed_request['user']['age']['min'] : 0;
$age_max = isset($signed_request['user']['age']) && isset($signed_request['user']['age']['max']) ? $signed_request['user']['age']['max'] : 199;