# Facebook age range in Graph API (JS SDK)?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

According [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425716/getting-an-authed-facebook-users-age-without-further-permissions-prompts) and the official documentation on [Signed Request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/), there should be within the encoded JSON payload a `user` object with an `age` object for the age range of the user.

However, when I decode the signature received through the JS SDK, I only have values for `user_id`, `code`, and a couple others, but no `user` object let alone age range. I've verified this in a stand-alone "connect" environment, as well as in a "tab application" environment. Further, when I test the JS SDK at the [Test Console](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/) I see no `user` object either.

**How can I get the user age range using just the JS SDK?**

Answer (score 1):

From the [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)
you referred,

> Fields and Values
>
> A signed_request is simply a data transfer mechanism and does not
>   imply any defined structure or format of data carried in the request.
>   However, within the Facebook Platform, the JSON object payload ***may***
>   contain some of the following fields and values:

Notice the ***may***.

> There's no way you can fetch age or age range through js sdk, without
>   getting permission

.

**p.s.** I havent tested in canvas app, but in page tabs, the signed request contains the age range but only when user likes your page :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get permission and caculate bitrthday date.